# Server doesn't respond to the first request

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

We're running an Apache server, and when we request a specific url, the browser will send the request, but it will sit there and wait until we stop it. Then, if you request the exact same url a second time. It loads instantly. We're not sure where to even begin to debug this, so my question would be, where would one begin to debug this? I've looked at the access logs, and error logs, and neither are really showing anything significant.

You can see it happening in firebug here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mgrH.jpg

Comment: I would try putting in a `die` statement at the very beginning of your route handler that you're trying to hit.  If it hits that, you know the issue is with the PHP code that follows, and not to do with apache

Comment: This isn't just happening on one page. That was just an example. It happens whenever a link leads to our website, or the url is typed directly. But it doesn't happen consistently either. Sometimes it works just fine. Othertimes, it takes a refresh to force the server to respond. Would there be an apache option that can be turned on to help monitor this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `LogLevel` to `debug` (or `trace8`, if you're on 2.4.x)? That should give you some more output in the error log. You could also run it under `gdb` and interrupt it, or `gcore` the process when it hangs, if you're comfortable with debuggers.

Comment: Thank you for the tips on reporting. I'll take a look at setting it up. But we noticed something new. It turns out only Mobile Chrome browsers are having this issue. So our Nexus Tablet, and Chrome for Android. We think it might have something to do with the bandwidth management settings. Has anyone experienced an issue like this before? This is as close to finding a similar issue as I can get: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gb_bZzmCnm4